# position of atomic propositons in bi-conditionals

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In implication position of $p$ and $q$ is important and can't be interchanged but I guess in case of bi-conditionals these two can be interchanged freely.

I mean to say $p\to q$ and $q\to p$ will not be equivilent necesserily but $p\leftrightarrow q$ and $q\leftrightarrow p$ convey the same meaning.

For example I have a statement

```
If you watch television your mind will decay and conversely.
```

so expressing it by using `if and only if`

(1) Your mind will decay if and only if you watch TV.

(2) you watch TV if and only if you mind decays

So are statements 1 and 2 equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. The biconditional connective $(\leftrightarrow)$ is commutative. This can easily be seen when we expand $$p \leftrightarrow q \equiv (p\rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow p)$$

Since the connective $\land$, as we know, is commutative, we have have $$\begin{align} p \leftrightarrow q & \equiv (p\rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow p)\\ \\ & \equiv (q\rightarrow p) \land (p \rightarrow q) \\ \\ &\equiv (q \leftrightarrow p)\end{align}$$

The truth of a biconditional statement  depends only on the agreement in the truth value of the propositions it connects.

So $$p \leftrightarrow q \equiv q \leftrightarrow p$$
and is true if and only if (both $p$ and $q$ are true) or (both $p$ and $q$ are false). Since this says the same as being true if and only if (both $q$ and $p$ are true) or (both $q$ and $p$ are false), which "side" of the biconditional connective each of $p, q$ appear really doesn't matter.

We can easily confirm this all by constructing a truth-table for each, and seeing their line-by-line agreement. Note the "quirky" symbol Wolfram Alpha uses to denote the connective $\iff$!

[image]

Comment: You have $p\bar{\veebar}q$ twice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, (1) and (2) are equivalent under propositional calculus.

You can see the difference with the [method of analytic tableaux](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux). You start with the negation of your original formula then apply a series of contradiction hunting rules. If each of the paths of the tableau is closed (i.e. contains a contradiction), then the original formula is a tautology. If some paths are open (i.e. do not contain contradictions), then each open path provides a counterexample to the original formula being a tautology.

Observe:

[image]

This next one, when completed, is closed, but I will leave it to you to finish. Here:

[image]

Do you see it now?

> The second tableau continues from "?" in almost exactly the same way as it does on the left.

Comment: Note that @amWhy's answer is much more direct, formal, and explanatory; mine is just for an extra perspective :)